# Git hook precommit doesn't working

Tags: javascript, git, githooks

It is a git hook for precommit 
It is assumed to execute esformatter command for every file modified (staged),

```
#!/bin/sh

for fil in $(git diff --name-only --staged | grep ".js"); do
 esformatter -i$ fil & git add $fil;
done

git commit -m "Adding format to files"
```

Actually I wanted that this code is executed in the same commit but I don't know how to do it.
The code actually works until the done part. But the files are not added to the commit obviusly, so that's why I need the commit part.

Regards

Comment: Would it be useful to use https://nathanhoad.net/git-amend-your-last-commit amend to achieve this? in the same commit

Comment: Obviusly when there are no answers there are downvotes bravoo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off think if this is the route you want to take. Modifying people's commits on the fly, is likely to cause hard to untangle messes down the road.

Secondly, if you want to to leave the changes in the same commit, you can simply remove the `git commit -m "Adding format to files"` line, so there's no separate commit done by the githook.

If that doesn't work, you could try to add it as a post-commit hook and do `git commit --amend`

Comment: I tried that... not making a commit but It is published without that change...  let me check again

Comment: So I don't need to add the files?

Comment: Yes it doesnt work , the files are changed but are unstaged. So when I make the git push it only sends the original changes not the formated code.
The formated code are not staged

Comment: git add $fil should be adding the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the file after modification.

```
esformatter -i$ fil & git add $fil
```

You probably intended to use `&&` here, not `&`. `&` will launch the formatter in the background, and, concurrently, stage the current contents of the file (which may not be formatted yet, or be in an unpredictable state even). I.e.:

- `task1 && task2` – execute `task1` synchronously, then execute `task2` if `task1` was successful
- `task1 & task2` – execute `task1` asynchronously and also execute `task2` (in this case, `task2` is executed synchronously because it is followed by `;` but newline has the same meaning)